# PHP command is executed before I tell it to

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

So, I'm trying to make an account creation page, but I'm having a simple error but since I'm very very new to PHP I don't understand what I've got wrong. I want it to do the command

`echo "Success!";`

after it has imported the data into the database. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];    

        DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email)',  array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password, 'email'=>$email));
        echo "Success!";
```

I know the database import code is probably wrong but that isn't what I'm worrying about right now, thank you. I'm using PHP 5.

Comment: `DB::query` isn't a standard PHP class/method. What does it do?

Comment: @ceejayoz It runs a MySQL query right?

Comment: I have no clue what it does, because it's not a default part of PHP. It could do literally anything - you either wrote the `DB` class or included someone else's `DB` class. Does it have documentation? Can you share the code for the DB class you're using?

Comment: (I would guess, if nothing else, that part of your problem is that `$username`, `$password`, and `$email` are never passed to `DB::query` in any way, and are thus entirely unavailable to its workings.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the echo is being called after the query method is called.
I guess your problem is that you are not validating if the insertion was succesfull before echoing it.
If that's the case, you should store the result in a variable and analyze it, and only if everything went fine, you echo "Success!".
Edit: Is this method yours? If it returns the result, you can make:

```
$result = DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email)',  array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password, 'email'=>$email));
```

And then you can see how to proceed.